# Effective way to find Nash equilibrium

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Is there any good algorithm for finding Nash equilibrium point, for one and repeated game theory? Thansk a lot for giving me some guidance.

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't (one known). It's hardness is captured by PPAD or FIXP, depending on what you want. For an intro, see here:
http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/kousha/dagstuhl14-etessami-tutorial-equilibrium.pdf